# Typeset Re(a+ib)

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How to typeset the "Re" of `Re(a+ib)` correctly inside an equation in LaTeX? I tried using `\mathcal` and `\mathbb`, but it does not give me the typical rounded R. I already saw in other documents.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use $\Re(a + ib)$

Comment: That's it, thanks! Sometimes we overlook the obvious :)

Answer (score 2):

Might `\mathfrak{Re}` be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

A typical math alphabet to denote the real and imaginary part of a complex number is `\mathscr` from the `mathrsfs` font.

[image: showcase]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\Re\undefined
\let\Im\undefined
\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{\mathscr{R}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{\mathscr{I}}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  a=\Re(a+ib)\\
  b=\Im(a+ib)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```